# Evaluate expressions within Vim

Tags: linux, editing

I want to be able to type a quick Mathematica expression, such as

- `550/3.` (e.g. common math),
- `Sum[i, {i, 0, n}]//TeXForm//ToString` (e.g. writing LaTeX document), or
- `{55, 1, 10, 40, 9}//Total` (e.g. do accounting calculations)

anywhere in any Vim buffer, visually select it, run a command, and see the result without leaving Vim.
How could I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I put together my own solution using VimScript and the Mathematica script interface.
This works for Linux; for other OSs modify as necessary.

First we create a file, say `~/bin/mathpipe.m` which takes a Mathematica expression from standard input and prints the result to standard output.
As far as I know, there's no built-in way to do this, please correct me if I'm wrong.
I'm using Mathematica 10;
consult the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframLanguageScripts.html) to check the right hashbang line for you (it may have changed from `MathematicaScript` to `wolfram`).

```
#!/usr/local/bin/MathematicaScript -script

(* read standard input, one line at a time, evaluating each one.
 print the InputForm of the evaluated last line. *)

val = Input[];
ret = val;
While[val = Input[]; val =!= EndOfFile, ret = val];
Print[ret];
```

Do `chmod +x ~/bin/mathpipe.m`.
We can run

```
$ echo "2+2" | ~/bin/mathpipe.m
4
```

Now, in our `.vimrc` we add one helper function:

```
function! s:get_visual_selection()
  " from http://stackoverflow.com/a/6271254/371334
  let [lnum1, col1] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
  let [lnum2, col2] = getpos("'>")[1:2]
  let lines = getline(lnum1, lnum2)
  let lines[-1] = lines[-1][: col2 - (&selection == 'inclusive' ? 1 : 2)]
  let lines[0] = lines[0][col1 - 1:]
  "return join(lines, "\n")
  return lines
endfunction
```

This gets the current (or most recent) visual selection and returns it as a list of string values.
With this we can define a command for echoing the evaluation of a selected expression (also goes in `.vimrc`):

```
function! Mathpipe1()
  let mathpipe = s:get_visual_selection()
  call writefile(mathpipe, '/tmp/mathpipein')
  silent !cat /tmp/mathpipein | ~/bin/mathpipe.m
endfunction
```

Add this line to map the function to the `<leader>m` key sequence:

```
xnoremap <leader>m :<c-h><c-h><c-h><c-h><c-h>call Mathpipe1()<CR>
```

So now if we visually select some text in Vim that is a Mathematica expression and hit `<leader>m` (usually `\m`), the result is shown in the output area on the ex command line.
Multi-line selections work too.

If we want the result printed in the current Vim buffer right below what we selected, we can do that too:

```
function! Mathpipe2()
  let mathpipe = s:get_visual_selection()
  call writefile(mathpipe, '/tmp/mathpipein')
  silent !cat /tmp/mathpipein | ~/bin/mathpipe.m > /tmp/mathpipeout
  normal `>
  r /tmp/mathpipeout
endfunction
xnoremap <leader>M :<c-h><c-h><c-h><c-h><c-h>call Mathpipe2()<CR>
```

With this, we can select text, hit `<leader>M` and the evaluation is printed on the next line.

Comment: (+1) Slight problems when you have `:set number`. Then on screen stuff gets mixed up but after `:wq` and a fresh open the file is OK.

Comment: @user21 yeah for me the screen loses a line and I have to hit `j` or something and it pops back

Comment: @user21, @Andrew, you can fix this issue by putting `redraw!` just above `endfunction` in any of the `Mathpipe` functions above. This will tell vim to redraw the screen.

Comment: I also made a Python version here: https://github.com/amacfie/vim-run-python3

Answer (score 6):

This package provides Vim-Mathematica integration:

- http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/2584/

Quoting from the package description:

> This is a Mathematica front end built into Vim, which is a high-end programmer's editor, highly compatible to vi but with lots of additional features. The front end is just an add-on for the editor, which can still be used as a standard editor for all kinds of ASCII files.
>
> The front end is a "text-mode' application which will run in any terminal (including, of course, xterms). The functionality is similar to the standard notebook interface, without graphics (there is, however, built-in support for external viewers like ghostview), but with greatly enhanced editing capabilities.

The package is from 1999.  That's the era of Vim 5 and Mathematica 4.  It very likely doesn't work out of the box today, but it should be a good starting point for implementing something similar with Vim 8 and Mathematica 11.